# Connect from container to host and execute commands with sudo in a secure manner

Tags: ssh, security, passwords, docker, sudo

I am able to ssh from a container to the host (after adding the container's public key into the host's authorized_keys file) and execute commands as user but need to supply the sudo password in plain text inside a bash script in the container which screams for more and better security. It might look like:

```
ssh -o "StrictHostKeyChecking=no" 172.17.0.1 sudo -S < <(echo "<HostSudoPassword>") apt install -y ntpstat
```

how can this be done better?

Comment: ssh-ing from container to host screams for better and totally defeats the purpose of process isolation.

Comment: @SathyajithBhat while I generally agree, this particular container is used to collect system (and networking) statistics from the host.